# Could not open Hibernate Session for transaction

Tags: hibernate, jndi

I am getting this error. please help me.

```
org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open Hibernate Session for transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Cannot open connection
 org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager.doBegin(HibernateTransactionManager.java:599)
 org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:374)
 org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:263)
 org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:101)
 org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
 org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
 $Proxy20.findFlierByID(Unknown Source)
 servlets.AwardServlet.doGet(AwardServlet.java:34)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
root cause

org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Cannot open connection
 org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.handledNonSpecificException(SQLStateConverter.java:126)
 org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:114)
 org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
 org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:52)
 org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.openConnection(ConnectionManager.java:449)
 org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.getConnection(ConnectionManager.java:167)
 org.hibernate.jdbc.JDBCContext.connection(JDBCContext.java:142)
 org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.begin(JDBCTransaction.java:85)
 org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1354)
 org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager.doBegin(HibernateTransactionManager.java:558)
 org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:374)
 org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:263)
 org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:101)
 org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
 org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
 $Proxy20.findFlierByID(Unknown Source)
 servlets.AwardServlet.doGet(AwardServlet.java:34)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
root cause

org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create JDBC driver of class '' for connect URL 'null'
 org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1452)
 org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1371)
 org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1044)
 org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalDataSourceConnectionProvider.getConnection(LocalDataSourceConnectionProvider.java:82)
 org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.openConnection(ConnectionManager.java:446)
 org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.getConnection(ConnectionManager.java:167)
 org.hibernate.jdbc.JDBCContext.connection(JDBCContext.java:142)
 org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.begin(JDBCTransaction.java:85)
 org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1354)
 org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager.doBegin(HibernateTransactionManager.java:558)
 org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:374)
 org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:263)
 org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:101)
 org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
 org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
 $Proxy20.findFlierByID(Unknown Source)
 servlets.AwardServlet.doGet(AwardServlet.java:34)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
root cause

java.lang.NullPointerException
 sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver.getProtocol(Unknown Source)
 sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver.knownURL(Unknown Source)
 sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver.acceptsURL(Unknown Source)
 java.sql.DriverManager.getDriver(Unknown Source)
 org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1437)
 org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1371)
 org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1044)
 org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalDataSourceConnectionProvider.getConnection(LocalDataSourceConnectionProvider.java:82)
 org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.openConnection(ConnectionManager.java:446)
 org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.getConnection(ConnectionManager.java:167)
 org.hibernate.jdbc.JDBCContext.connection(JDBCContext.java:142)
 org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.begin(JDBCTransaction.java:85)
 org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1354)
 org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager.doBegin(HibernateTransactionManager.java:558)
 org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:374)
 org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:263)
 org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:101)
 org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
 org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
 $Proxy20.findFlierByID(Unknown Source)
 servlets.AwardServlet.doGet(AwardServlet.java:34)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
```

I have seen many examples on net but i could'nt solve  this problem. so please help me.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with Hibernate. Your connection setting is not correct. (i see nullpointer while getting both protocol and url as root cause). Paste your connection configuration. (Why is this under jndi? are you getting connection from server data source)

Comment: The root cause says `org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create JDBC driver of class '' for connect URL 'null'`. Check whether you are specifying any JDBC driver class and also the connection URL.

Answer (score 0):

I recently faced this issue. What i found out is that due to connection loss to the Database from application, this error pops up. There might be some operation that you are doing while DB is offline.

Please check your connection related parameters.

Hope this helps.